# Difference between Response::view and View::make in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I understand that `Response::view` actually ends up calling `View::make` as part of the process, but why would I return one vs the other from a controller ?

Can someone explain what the difference in output is between them ?

Answer (score 9):

They are both the same things.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php#L41) :

```
public static function view($view, $data = array(), $status = 200, array $headers = array()) {
    $app = Facade::getFacadeApplication();
    return static::make($app['view']->make($view, $data), $status, $headers);
}
```

We can see that `Response::view()` calls `View::make()`, uses that to create a response with the default status being 200 OK and no additional HTTP headers.

You'll need to use `Response::view()` over `View::make()` when you need to return a non-default status code or additional headers.

Moreover, [this post](http://laravel.io/forum/03-09-2014-responseview-vs-responsemakeviewmake-and-error-pages?page=1#reply-3035) on Laravel.io confirms that `Response::view()` is just a shortcut for `Response::make(View::make())` added after the initial Laravel 4 beta commit.

Comment: So calling Response instead of View doesn't return any header information along with the rendered HTML from `View::make()`? I know they end up displaying the same information in a browser, but what would be different in another interface, like the command line?